# Publish Static Website Using Azure

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a single html file (index.html) and an image that I tried to host on Azure.

I put them in a dropbox folder and synced, the website got published and Azure status shows running.

I go the webpage and it shows:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Do I need to add anything to make the site work?

Comment: Do you see the files when you use Kudu (`https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net`)? Is `index.html` included in the list of Default Documents on your Application Settings blade in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Also, is your domain-name properly forwarded? Do you get the same message when you access `http://yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net` directly?)

Comment: @Dai Yes, index.html is there.

Comment: @Dai yes, I get You do not have permission to view this directory or page. when I access my website directly.

Comment: I suggest you contact Azure Support. I understand that Deploy-from-Dropbox is still not yet mature for production use.

Comment: @Dai No in Kudu I don't see the files...no index.html and my image file is there. Site folder shows D:\home ....

Comment: @Dai I don't see the files...any way the files themselves may not have been uploaded or smthmg...

Comment: @Rafael - please edit your question with all these details you're posting here, vs scattering them across several comments.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Hi, there are not many details, site files are uploaded fine, I can see the wwwroot folder..yet it is giving error.

Comment: @Rafael you missed the point - this is turning into a comment stream (and i'll be deleting my comments shortly, due to this) - this makes it very difficult to read concisely. And you are responding to questions, in comments. Little details that might help. It's *trivial* to edit your question. And that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks, i will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

In general, when you access your web app : `https://{webapp-name}.azurewebsites.net` directly, you'd better make sure that the default documents you defined of your web app could be found within your web app. You could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [Azure App Service Editor](https://developingdane.com/azure-app-service-editor/) to check whether your files exist.

> @Dai No in Kudu I don't see the files...no index.html and my image file is there.

As I known, Azure would sync the changes (e.g add/remove file(s) in your DropBox deployment repository) and deploy the changes to your web app.

**Note:** When you delete file(s) synced from DropBox under your website folder(e.g `D:\home\site\wwwroot\`), the deleted file(s) couldn't be synced from DropBox in subsequent deployments. You could log into Azure Portal, choose your web app, select "APP DEVELOPMENT > Deployment options", check your deployment logs as follows to see the synchronization log.

[image]

According to your description, I assumed that you could log into Azure Portal, disconnect your deployment options and setup your DropBox deployment again. Also, you need to check the synchronization log mentioned above and check your files in your website folder via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [Azure App Service Editor](https://developingdane.com/azure-app-service-editor/).

Comment: the files are there in site\wwwroot and i disconncted and synced again, still getting the same error :(((

Comment: Could you please provide the files structure of your website under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` via Kudu? Is this site [url](http://rafael.azurewebsites.net/) yours?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruce, i disconnected and it worked, it was some sync issue... That url is not mine though.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.